# Is it possible in Mathematica to get a step-by-step evaluation of the following?

Tags: evaluation, wolfram-alpha-queries, debugging

Is it possible in Mathematica (or `WolframAlpha["...]"`) to get a step-by-step evaluation of the following?

```
    f[n_, x_] := 
 Sum[(-1)^m (n!/(m! (n - 2 m)!)) (2 x)^(n - 2 m), {m, 0, Floor[n/2]}]
f[3, x]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[n_, x_] := 
 Sum[(-1)^m (n!/(m! (n - 2 m)!)) (2 x)^(n - 2 m), {m, 0, Floor[n/2]}]
trace = Trace@f[6, x];
steps = trace[[3 ;; -2 , -1]] // ReleaseHold;
acc = steps // Accumulate;

{Range@Length@steps, steps, acc} //
   Transpose //
  Prepend[#, { "Step #", "Current Term", "Accumulated Sum"}] & //
 Grid[#, Dividers -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
f[n_, x_] := Module[{sum = 0, currentTerm},
  First@Last@Reap@Do[
      currentTerm = (-1)^m (n!/(m! (n - 2 m)!)) (2 x)^(n - 2 m);
      Sow[{m, currentTerm, sum += currentTerm}],
      {m, 0, Floor[n/2]}
      ]
  ]
```

Now do

```
data = f[6, x];
Grid[PrependTo[data, {"m", "current term", "current sum"}], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]